# Is checking the value of a dangling pointer safe or Undefined Behavior?

Tags: c++, pointers, dangling-pointer

We can only de-reference a valid pointer and we can only check the address that a dangling built-in pointer points to. We cannot access its value (the value in the address of object it is pointing to).

```
int* ptr = nullptr;
if(ptr) // != 0x00000000
   std::cout << *ptr << '\n';

ptr = new int(1000);

if(ptr) // != 0x00000000
   std::cout << *ptr << '\n';

delete ptr; // still pointing at the address of that dynamic object but that object has been destroyed.

if(ptr) // succeeds or undefined behavior?
   std::cout << *ptr << '\n'; // of course UB here
```

So it is clear for me but what matter me only is whether checking a pointer value is safe or yields UB? `if(ptr)`. Because let's assume that I didn't access the value in that address like in `std::cout << *ptr`.

Comment: Checking whether a pointer is `nullptr` unfortunately does not check whether the pointed-to object has been destroyed or not. (Obviously, if the pointer is `nullptr` there is no pointed-to object, but the flip side does not hold.)

Comment: @fabian: Thanks a lot! it was my bad I've forgotten the pointer operator,

Comment: It's implementation defined behavior since C++14, undefined before C++14: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44182049/pointers-in-c-after-delete

Answer (score 4):

> Is checking the value of a dangling pointer safe or Undefined Behavior?

It's not UB (since C++14), but "safe" depends on what you expect. There is no guarantee about the result of such check. It could be true or false. Assuming that a pointer is valid based on `if(ptr)` is not safe in general.

Comment: Looks like it was UB: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44182049/pointers-in-c-after-delete

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Edited.

Answer (score 4):

It is safe to dereference a non-null pointer only if it is actually pointing at a valid object, and unfortunately there is no way to test for that condition in C/C++ <sup>1</sup>.

<sup>1: unless you manually keep track of the addresses of your valid objects and can thus search for the pointed-at address in your own tracking data.</sup>

It is not *undefined* behavior to test whether a pointer is equal to null or not.  However, per [`[basic.stc.general]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.stc.general#4), apparently after a block of memory is destroyed/reclaimed, any use of any pointer value referring to any part within that block is *implementation-defined* behavior:

> When the end of the duration of a region of storage is reached, the values of all pointers representing the address of any part of that region of storage become invalid pointer values.
>
> Indirection through an invalid pointer value and passing an invalid pointer value to a deallocation function have undefined behavior.
>
> **Any other use of an invalid pointer value has implementation-defined behavior.**

So, some people may argue that it means a pointer holding the address of a destroyed object MAY OR MAY NOT even be legal to compare against other pointers or even `nullptr` itself, since the address is invalid.  Only the compiler gets to decide if that is legal or not.

Comment: not perfectly well-defined, rather implementation-defined. See comment on the other answer

Comment: Checking if a pointer is equal to null or not is a well-defined operation. What you do with that pointer is a different matter.

Comment: @RemyLebeau The wording of the standard is "Any other [than dereferencing] use of an invalid pointer value has implementation-defined behavior.", is there a separate section relating to nullptr comparisons that contradict this?

Comment: @Frank `if (ptr)` is essentially just shorthand for `if (ptr != 0)` or `if (ptr != nullptr)`. The standard in [`[conv.ptr]`](https://eel.is/c++draft/conv.ptr) says: "*A null pointer constant can be converted to a pointer type; the result is the null pointer value of that type... Two null pointer values of the same type shall compare equal.*" I read that as saying that if `ptr` has a null value then the comparison is guaranteed to be true, otherwise if it does not have a null value then the comparison is guaranteed to be false. What section are you looking at?

Comment: @RemyLebeau [`[new.delete.single]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/new.delete.single#12) for `delete` rendering the pointer "invalid", and [`[basic.stc.general]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.stc.general#4) for using an invalidated pointer being implementation-defined (which is still well-defined, just not portably safe).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for `int* ptr;`, the expression `ptr` is always safe. The behaviour of the program remains defined. But

- The specific value of a pointer is implementation-defined. [Ellipsis , emphasis mine]

> [6.8.2.3.4] A value of a pointer type that is a pointer to or past the end of an object **represents the address of the first
> byte in memory (6.7.1) occupied by the object** or the first byte in memory after the end of the storage
> occupied by the object, respectively. [...]
> **The value representation of pointer types is implementation-defined.** Pointers
> to layout-compatible types shall have the same value representation and alignment requirements (6.7.6).
> [Note: Pointers to over-aligned types (6.7.6) have no special representation, but their range of valid values is
> restricted by the extended alignment requirement. — end note]

- `nullptr` is guaranteed to be equal(`==`) to 0 and `NULL`.
- In boolean context, `nullptr` evaluates to `false`, ALL other values, **no matter whether they represent an address of valid objects**, evaluate to `true`.
- `delete` does not modify the pointer. **EDIT:** Or maybe it does, see the discussion in comments.
- Pointers have same initialization rules as integers, meaning locals, non-static members are not initialized. `int* ptr; assert(ptr==nullptr);` does NOT hold in general. But global pointers are zero-initialized and thus evaluate to false at the start.

All taken together, although the program is safe, it is quite easy to make it nondeterministic at best.

Comment: "`delete` does not modify the pointer" is [not necessarily true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002055/is-the-pointer-guaranteed-to-preserve-its-value-after-delete-in-c) as far as I know.

Comment: Answer has `int ptr;`, yet code is `int *ptr;`.  Is that intended?

Comment: @NathanPierson But how can it modify the pointer? AFAIK the signature is `void operator delete(void* ptr)` - takes a copy of the pointer, so it cannot modify the variable itself, right?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica No, it's not. Thank you, in the future feel free to fix any typos in my answers :)

Comment: @Quimby I think it's the difference between the `delete` expression and the `operator delete` function that gets invoked. It may be a pretty academic point anyway if compilers are permitted to do so by the standard but, in practice, do not elect to do so.

Comment: @NathanPierson You might be right, the standard in 7.6.2.8 calls the latter as deallocation function. So there is a difference, although the chapter does not state anything about the value after `delete`. Sadly.