Using the address of a dangling variable without dereferencing it
Is using (but not dereferencing) the address of a captured variable that is out of range, undefined behavior ?
#include <iostream>

auto foo()
{
    int i = 42;
    return [&] { std::cout << &i << '\n'; };
}

int main()
{
    auto lmb = foo();
    lmb();
}

I understand a variable cannot be accessed after it no longer exists, but I'm wondering if the lambda simply captures the address when the variable exists and then stores it.

Using the address of a captured live variable that is out of ranges is well-defined behavior.  Using the address of a captured deceased variable is undefined behavior.  Technically, even [p=&i]{ std::cout << p << "\n"; } would be undefined behavior, because all pointers to the deceased object become inaccessible (including printing of the pointer value, not dereferencing it) after the object they point to becomes deceased.  There is a behavior, but what that  behavior is is undefined as to how it works in the C++ abstract machine (let alone how the implementation would handle it).

UB. If you have really any use case for dangling pointer value then convert the pointer value (when not yet dangling) to intptr_t and capture it by value.

@Eljay that's good to know. I thought only dereferencing causes UB. Although I cannot see a proper use case for it anyway.

Calling foo is fine, calling lmd() is UB.

Technically only indirecting through and calling an deallocation function on a dangling pointer are undefined behavior – Doing anything else with a dangling pointer (like printing it or even just copying it) is implementation-defined behavior. (currently this is covered by basic.stc.general (4), but CWG 2822 (DR) moved it to basic.compound (4).

As per the linked answer (at the end of the comment), reading a pointer after the object it was pointing to was deleted (or I suppose end-of-life'd, from an automatic variable going out of scope as well) is undefined behavior in C++11, but is implementation defined behavior in C++14 (and later, I presume). C++ has so much subtle nuances. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44182938/4641116
