# C++ try/catch after deleting a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, try-catch

After I searched about how to verify if a pointer is deleted in C++, i found out that there is no certain way, some really ugly work-around or smart pointers (I first want to understand how normal pointers works). My question is why C++ crashes when I try in a try/catch to show the value of a deleted pointer? shouldn't it handle the crash and just print the exception ??

```
void main()
{
    int *a = new int[5];

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        *(a + i) = i;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if (*(a + i) != NULL) // useless verify, cuz if it would be NULL, it 
                              //would crash imediately
        {
            cout << (a + i) << ", " << *(a + i) << endl;
        }
    }

    delete a;
    cout << a << ", ";// << *a << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        try{
            cout << (a + i) << ", " << *(a + i) << endl;
        }
        catch (int e)
        {
            cout << "Error: " << e << endl;
        }
    }

    cin.get();
}
```

Comment: it's called **undefined behavior** in c++

Comment: Does it throw exception, if not then what are you trying to catch?

Comment: Messing up with pointers doesn't throw an exception.  It just does whatever.

Comment: maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23621677/what-happens-to-the-pointer-itself-after-delete

Comment: `*(a + i) != NULL` Is useless to verify, since the value of `*(a + i)` is not a pointer, hence, you are effectively comparing such a value with a value of `0`.

Comment: Your program invokes undefined behavior. It should **not** _handle the crash and just print the exception_. Making parallels between the C++ and other languages is often counter-productive.

Answer (score 4):

```
try{
        cout << (a + i) << ", " << *(a + i) << endl;
    }
    catch (int e)
    {
        cout << "Error: " << e << endl;
    }
```

You can catch an exception only if one is thrown. Accessing freed memory is Undefined Beahvior and does not throw an exception, so there is nothing to catch.

Comment: Thanks! easy and understandable answer :)

Answer (score 0):

First for array deletion the syntax is `delete [] a;` secondly your try catch block is not for handling corrupted address, and unfortunate there is not exception handling for memory access violation in C++.

Comment: What about `void main`?

Comment: @KillzoneKid, you are true but his question is specifically regarding try/catch.

Answer (score -1):

There are no **exception thrown** in this case, simply **undefined behavior**. Exceptions are made to explicitly catch *exceptions that are being thrown*.

Also, use `delete [] a;` instead of `delete a;` to delete an array.

Also, when we `delete` memory, the memory does not actually get **deleted** but is **free to be overwritten** from now on.

What `cout` would print does not say much on whether the pointer was `deleted`.

Comment: *The former only deletes the first element.* I think it is UB.